# Create your own update system in Java

Tags: java, swing, javafx, deployment, auto-update

I would like to implement a Java application that can download a new version (.jar file) from a given URL, and then update itself at runtime.

We retrieve the versions available on the internet
We compare them with the current version
If the current version is newer, a message is displayed telling the user that there is no update possible
Otherwise, the user is informed of the possible versions and given the choice when to download.
If he wants to download one, download the one he chooses
Then we restart the program
The program at startup must see if there is a new version, and if necessary, take it ==> use a launcher

What is the best way to do this and is it possible?

Comment: You can google for "jnlp"

Comment: Better not, jnlp (Java webstart) will no longer be supported since java 11

Comment: @talex See [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf) of 2018-03 by Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Getdown](https://github.com/threerings/getdown). This solution precisely addresses your problem. The docs say:

> (GetDown) is a system for deploying Java applications to end-user computers, as well as keeping those applications up to date.

Don't bother with Java Webstart as since java 11 it will no longer be available.